# How do I pass data to view model for a user control in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a list of Block objects.  Each block has a name and a price.  Along with other properties that are not important here

Block 1 - £10
Block 2 - £20

I have implemented a user control which displays a block.

This control has its own view model which I bind the view to.  E.g. I have a label with `Content="{Binding Name}"`.

I have a separate view which contains a stack panel. This will be filled up with multiple Block Controls.

How do I pass each block from my list of blocks into the View Model of the user control?

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view model for the stack panel view. Expose a collection of the block view models in this view model.

Bind this collection to something like an ItemsControl inside the stack panel in the view. Set up the templates so that your user control is used to display every item.

Every control instantiated by the ItemsControl will be associated with an element from your collection. This will result in every user control associated with its own view model.

Update - here is some code

The main page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BlockViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:BlockView></local:BlockView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The main page code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

The main page view model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<BlockViewModel> BlockViewModels
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        BlockViewModels = new ObservableCollection<BlockViewModel>();
        BlockViewModels.Add(new BlockViewModel { CurrentBlock = new Block { Name = "Block 1", Price = 10 } });
        BlockViewModels.Add(new BlockViewModel { CurrentBlock = new Block { Name = "Block 2", Price = 20 } });
    }
}
```

The block model:

```
public class Block
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Price
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The block view model:

```
public class BlockViewModel
{
    public Block CurrentBlock
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The block view:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentBlock.Name}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text=" - "></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentBlock.Price}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry I dont really understand this?  Could you post a little code snippet?  I understand the ItemsControl side of things.  I am struggling on the list of ViewModels.  I wan to put code in here but everytime I press enter it posts comment!  I have created 3 block objects.  I then looped through these and created 3 view models which I added to my list.  When I tried this, I got nothing displayed.  What is correct syntax for the XAML in my control?  Also, I am assuming I dont need to set DataContext?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake with the binding.  When I create the list of view models in my stack panel's view model, I am assuming its correct to create a new view model and then set the view model's property to the current block?  Is there a better way to do this with less code?

Comment: I added some example code to clarify things. As for creation of models and view models - it's probably a separate topic. We use Unity to create our view models. Our models often come from the server as a result of a WCF request.